# Erro com inserção Mysql com JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Estou executando esse código:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package br.com.caelum.jdbc;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class TestaInsercao {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        Connection connection = DataBase.getConnection();
        String nome = "Notebook";
        String descricao = "Notebook core i5";
        String sql = "insert into produto (nome, descricao) values (?,?)";

        PreparedStatement comando = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        comando.setString(1, nome);
        comando.setString(2, descricao);

        boolean resultado = comando.execute();
        System.out.println(resultado);

        ResultSet resultSet = comando.getGeneratedKeys();
        while (resultSet.next()) {

            String id = resultSet.getString("id");
            System.out.println("Chave gerado: " + id);

        }

        resultSet.close();
        comando.close();
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

E estou recebendo a seguinte SQLException na linha `comando.getString("id")`:

> run: false Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Column
>   'id' not found.   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1167)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5733)   at
>   br.com.caelum.jdbc.TestaInsercao.main(TestaInsercao.java:33)
>   C:\Users\bahia\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 FALHA NA CONSTRUÇÃO (tempo total: 0 segundos)

Eu sei que elá está dizendo que não está encontrando a coluna id, mas ela existe, e quando vou para o Mysql Workbench e faço um select na minha tabela, mostra que o produto foi adicionado, mesmo mostrando false e dando exception no java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua ID é uma `String` mesmo?

Se ela for auto incremento, faz um teste com este código no local do seu ResultSet e do seu While:

```java
try (ResultSet resultSet = comando.getGeneratedKeys()) {
  if (resultSet.next()) {
    long id = resultSet.getLong(1);
    System.out.println("Chave gerado: " + id);
  }else {
    throw new SQLException("Creating user failed, no ID obtained.");
  }
}
```

Comment: foi.. pode me explicar porque ?

Comment: O banco estava criando sua chave como int ou long e você estava esperando uma String no retorno, basicamente por isso. O `resultSet.getLong(1);` pega o retorno da primeira coluna da tabela, a de  index 1.